# Group by and Having clause in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

**Schema:**

> **place(pid, name, type, lat, lng, deleted)**

---

> I want to select count of places, grouping them by their type and
>   having a distance of < 10 KM from a particular lat, lng

**Query:**

```
SELECT count(p.type) as count
FROM (place as p)
where p.deleted != 1
 and p.pid in
    (
    select p2.pid,
            IFNULL(acos(sin((18.5236 *pi()/180)) * sin((p2.lat*pi()/180))+cos((18.5236 *pi()/180)) * cos((p2.lat *pi()/180)) * cos(((73.8478 - p2.lng)*pi()/180))) * 6371.009, 0) AS distance
    from place p2
    having `distance` < 10
    )
group by p.type;
```

**Error:**

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

That is because I am selecting 2 columns i.e **pid** and **distance** in the sub select query. But without using a 2nd select column how can I calculate the distance.

Comment: add your IFNULL(acos...)<10 to a where condition in your inner query and remove it from the select clause.

Comment: your subquery should return only one column.

Comment: @wxyz without using an alias, just calculate the distance in having?

Comment: @wxyz Yeah that did the job. Thanks a lot bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your script like this

```
SELECT  count(p.type) AS count,
        -- remove this if not necessary
        SUM(IFNULL(acos(sin((18.5236 *pi()/180)) * sin((p.lat*pi()/180))+cos((18.5236 *pi()/180)) * cos((p.lat *pi()/180)) * cos(((73.8478 - p.lng)*pi()/180))) * 6371.009, 0)) AS distance

FROM place AS p
WHERE p.deleted != 1
GROUP BY p.type
HAVING SUM(IFNULL(acos(sin((18.5236 *pi()/180)) * sin((p.lat*pi()/180))+cos((18.5236 *pi()/180)) * cos((p.lat *pi()/180)) * cos(((73.8478 - p.lng)*pi()/180))) * 6371.009, 0)) < 10
```